# Xcode: Swift - How to make bottom line border color that appears/disappear when the text field is edited?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uikit, uitextfield

I have already added an extension for UITextField to display the bottom borders with color which is working. However, my intention is for the bottom border to appear when user taps on the textfield to edit the text and disappear the border when done edit. I have referred to other stackoverflow question regarding this but I could't find an answer or question that involved both bottom borders and appear/disappear when editing.

```
extension UITextField {

    func addBottomBorder() {
        let bottomline = CALayer()
        bottomline.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y:self.frame.size.height - 1, width: self.frame.size.width,height: 1)
        bottomline.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        borderStyle = .none
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomline)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
    
}
```

I'm quite new to swift and Ios development. would be helpful if someone can show on what I should add to the extension file to make it possible for border appear and disappear when editing.

**Update**

View controller

```
     func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        movementTextField.addBottomBorder()
        notesTextField.addBottomBorder()
        descriptionTextField.addBottomBorder()
        shotSize.addBottomBorder()
        shotNameTextField.addBottomBorder()
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        movementTextField.removeBottomBorder()
        notesTextField.removeBottomBorder()
        descriptionTextField.removeBottomBorder()
        shotSize.removeBottomBorder()
        shotNameTextField.removeBottomBorder()
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            textField.resignFirstResponder()
        }
```

**Extension Update**

```
 extension UITextField {
    
    func addBottomBorder() {
        let bottomline = CALayer()
        bottomline.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y:self.frame.size.height - 1, width: self.frame.size.width,height: 1)
        bottomline.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 255.0/255.0, blue: 255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        borderStyle = .none
        self.layer.addSublayer(bottomline)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
    
    func removeBottomBorder() {
        let removebottomline = CALayer()
        removebottomline.frame = CGRect(x: 0,y:self.frame.size.height - 1, width: self.frame.size.width,height: 1)
        removebottomline.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 30.0/255.0, green: 30.0/255.0, blue: 30.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        borderStyle = .none
        self.layer.addSublayer(removebottomline)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Comment: In textfield delgate function didBeginEditing you can appear border and on edidEndEditing fucntion you can disappear border.

Comment: @Kudos hi,can you explain with some code example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with below steps:

```
@IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField    
@IBOutlet var surnameTextField: UITextField    

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameTextField.delegate = self           
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //didBegin method(when you start editing in textfield) 
//To addBorder for specific Textfield just make a if else condition like:
    if textField == nameTextField {
      addBottomBorder()
    }
                                                    
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  //EndEiditing method(when you end editing in textfield) 
  //To removeBorder for specific Textfield just make a if else condition like:
  if textField == nameTextField {
    removeBottomBorder()
   }
  
}
```

Comment: thank you for the help. However, when i tap to edit the textfield, all the textfield is getting bottom border. How to make only tapped textfield have bottom border. I have posted the update above.

Comment: @AbednegoDavid I have updated My answer. Also Could you please mark it correct answer as I answered correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
    @IBOutlet var textFieldFirst: UITextField   
    @IBOutlet var textFieldSecond: UITextField          
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textFieldFirst = self      
        textFieldSecond = self
    }
    
    
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {    //didBegin method
         if (textFieldFirst = textField)
              {
               textFieldFirst.addBottomBorder()
              }
        // marks rest condition in ifelse or have switch condition 
    
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {  //EndEiditing method
    if (textFieldFirst = textField)
              {
                textFieldFirst.removeBottomBorder()
              }
         // marks rest condition in ifelse or have switch condition 
    
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool {   
      textField.resignFirstResponder()
    
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the help. However, when i tap to edit the textfield, all the textfield is getting bottom border. Can you help to explain how to make only one tapped textfield to have bottom border at a time?

Comment: @AbednegoDavid  Refer the updated answer. In case of any concern or require left out. Please feel free to connect on same.